# Sass import partial content in another sass file

Tags: css, sass

I would like to use sass in my new project, but I can't find a better way for cross file usage. Here is the example

```
/*a.scss*/
@mixin mixA{
 ....
}
.classInA{
  ...
}

/*b.scss*/
@import 'a'
....
```

I want to use the mixA without having other scss(such as classInA) being imported into b.scss, how can I do it?

Comment: Always work with 1 master stylesheet in your sass (eg: main.scss). Over there import every substylesheet (eg: _mixins.scss, _defaults.scss). Don't forget that the order is important, so mixins should be loaded first.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way to do it is to put all your mixins in a general mixins file, then, import that file into another general file where you import all the SCSS (or SASS) files.

```
/*mixins.scss*/

//Here goes all your mixins

/*main.scss*/

@import 'mixins';
@import 'header';
@import 'footer';
```

And import the mixins you want in the files needed.

Comment: thank you, I will collect all the mixins into one file.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to import other sass file simply do :

```
@import 'path/sass-file';
@import 'path/sass-file';
@import 'path/sass-file';
```

If you would like extend any of already created class in your scss you can do it like this :

```
.new-custom-class {

  @extend .custom-class;
  /* you can add some options in here also */

  }
```

Comment: If the file is in the same directory simply use `@import 'sass-file';`